# PHP Editing and displaying text from a .txt file

Tags: apache2, ubuntu, php, database

I have a file named 'views.txt' which contains '0'.
When the user loads the page,  I want the script to re-write the text document to one higher from the last.

Example;

```
<?php
$a = file_get_contents("views.txt")
$views = $a + 1;
file_put_contents("views.txt",$views);
echo $views;
?>
```

It won't display anything.

I'm unable to use MySQL, so I'm using text files. :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would guess that the path to `views.txt` is not relative to the working directory of the file.  For safety reasons, you should probably specify the full path to the file; i.e., `/path/to/views.txt`).

You can also use [getcwd](http://php.net/manual/en/function.getcwd.php) to display the current working directory, so the location of "views.txt" will likely be `getcwd() . "/views.txt"`.

Answer (score 0):

Your string might really be `0\n`, where `\n` is a newline. Try using:

```
<?php
$views_file = "views.txt";
$allviewfile = file($views_file, FILE_IGNORE_NEW_LINES);
$a = $allviewfile[0];
$views = $a + 1;
file_put_contents($views_file,$views);
echo $views;
?>
```